# Need Captcha Verification before accessing a hyperlink?

Tags: user, authentication

I installed a plugin (Delete My Account) which lets me place a **hyperlink** anywhere inside an article or module, which when clicked, deletes the account of the registered user from the front-end. What i want is to trigger a **captcha verification** pop-up box (or something like that) whenever that hyperlink is clicked & the user should only be able to access that hyperlink when he inputs the captcha verification correctly. Is there a way out?

Comment: You can either create a plugin which will trigger the event, or you can dive into the module code and place the captcha there. Might be an idea to first contact the developer and see if they have any future plans for captcha integration

Comment: is there a plugin you know which can do the trick for me. BTW can i make a captcha verification for users to access any specific page. I mean, i can place the account deleting link on one page which should only be accessible by inputing the captcha code correctly on some other page?

Comment: There are no plugins that I personally know of that can do as you are requesting. Someone else on JSE might know of one. I suppose if you go into the module code, you can add a captcha section within the modal so that when submitting the form, it will only delete the account if the captcha answer is correct. Perhaps start doing something along these lines and edit your question with the code you've tried and where exactly you're struggling :)

Answer (score 2):

Showing re-captcha before deleting user's account will be a complex task.

If you can customize the code, here is an suggestion, which can be fruitful for you.

- An extra text box can be displayed in which user can fill the text string. This value can be any mathematics calculation or any pattern of string. You need to store the expected value in session so that you can verify it later.
- You can verify that text when user confirm the request of deleting his account. But you need to change the code of Javascript to send the value of text box.

Hope it helps you.